# Table with a single row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to have a table which can only have one record. I am planning to use it for configuration purposes. Although I know this is not a use case for SQL databases and better suited for KV stores. But I want to use this in conjunction with existing transactions. In other words, I want to have a KV store where each key maps to a table with a single row. Is it possible to enforce a single row limitation/constraint to tables in MySQL or other SQL databases?

Comment: Yes, why not. Many web-based systems are using similar ways to save settings / configurations.

Comment: @Raptor Is there any constraint that limits the records size to one?

Comment: I have done this before.  An example would be if you have a SQL table whose purpose is to serve as a lock/mutex of some sort.  The constraint for limiting to one record should come from the app, which never does an insert.

Comment: @zeronone The length of the record depends on the data type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html

Comment: @Raptor Sorry I meant the number of records. I want to table to have only a single record and no more. "Singleton Table" (dont know if this wording is correct though).

Comment: You mean a lot of tables with single record? From documentation, *"MySQL has no limit on the number of tables. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of files that represent tables. Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables."*

Comment: A better (more conventional) design would be to one row per key in the same table and a unique constraint on the key.

Comment: what about an insert trigger ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of enum constraint and unique constaint, to ensure there is only one row in the table

```
CREATE TABLE example_tbl (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    -- this ensures unique_value column only accepts 'some_value'
    unique_value ENUM('some_value') NOT NULL,
    -- this ensures unique_value column is unique
    UNIQUE (unique_value)
 );
```

[sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0ea34/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a condition while inserting a record to the table to check if a value exists. Usually this is done from the application side. You can use an insert or update condition if a record exists.

```
Query1= SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
```

If Query1 returns a value then do an update on the table else do an insert.

Comment: I was looking for some built-in constraint in MySQL. Also this appraoch has its drawbacks, for it to work correctly, one need to use a very high isolation level, like serializable.